# HTML hover border when we hover the all other element moves how to solve issue?

Tags: html, css, hover, border

below i am writing the HTML code in which having issue 
when we add border to the element in hover the issue arises you can see that even 
so the question is how to get rid off from moving element we want rest element to stay still only 
in many of my webpages this problem arises
so please help me with the detail answer what is the reason and not just solving this particular code
https://codepen.io/shahrishit9/pen/aEdJWa?editors=1100
in this codepan also we can se the same things happen 
please check it

```css
body{background-color:pink;font-family-arial;font-size:1.10em;}
#para{
margin:0px 50px 30px 50px;}
#footerMenu {text-align:center;}
#creator{text-align:center;}
a{padding:0px 10px;margin:10px;text-decoration:none;color:black;}
a:hover{border: solid 2px lightblue;}
```

```html
<HTML lang ="en">
  <head>
    <title>
      My new footer
    </title>
    <meta charset = utf-8>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <section id="para">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </section>
      <footer>
      <section id="footerMenu">
        <a href=https://www.instagram.com/>Instagram</a>
        <a href=https://www.facebook.com/>Facebook</a>
      <a href=https://www.twitter.com/>Twitter</a>
    <a href="">Site Map</a>
    
      </section>
<section Id="creator">
         design and code by Rishit Shah
  </section>
      </footer>
    </div>
    
  </body>
  </HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when you added the border, the height of the element increases additionally 2px extra. That extra height showing like the element moving a little bit. You can apply the transparent border for your element initially then you apply the actual border on hover. In that way you don't get differentiation on the element position.

```
li {
   line-height:10px;
   display:block;
   padding:10px;
   max-width:150px;
   text-align:center;
   margin:10px; 
   border:1px solid transparent;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/p4qmtrrt/)

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this:

```
a{border:solid 2px transparent;} // Add this with your other css property.
a:hover{
  border-color: lightblue;
}
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/codepenforkapil/pen/LOvopP?editors=0100)

Comment: Sorry Dude, new to stackoverflow. I don't know how to write answer properly. https://codepen.io/codepenforkapil/pen/LOvopP?editors=0100